# Python Selenium ZALANDO BOT

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I am doing a bot to fast purchase item on ZALANDO.IT (but the platform is the same for all EU sites). Anyway the bot seems work very well but Zalando block my request when I try to do the payment with an ERROR PAGE that obviously does not appear when I do the checkout manually.
So I think that there are a sort of control against bot.

How I can trick the site so that I will not blocked?
Maybe the gecko driver is the problem? I see a bot image on the navigation bar of firefox (see the attach).

[GeckoDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUqOv.png)

At the end you will find the part of code that do the checkout (after item is added to the cart)

I am blocked at the last two line of code.
In addition to this when I try to go to the cart after I added the item to the cart Zalando ask me always a login also if I did it previously (manually this does not happen at all)

````
driver.get('https://www.zalando.it/checkout/address')

firstAddressIdBttn = 'delivery-destination-tab-0'
secondAddressClassNameBttn = 'z-1-button__content'
paymentIdBttn = 'payz-selection-bottom-submit'

exceptNow = True
skipNext = False
skipNextNext = False
iteration = 0
while exceptNow:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(firstAddressIdBttn).click()
        exceptNow = False
    except:
        try: 
            driver.find_element_by_class_name(secondAddressClassNameBttn).click()
            exceptNow = False
            skipNext = True
        except:
            try:
                login(driver, False, iteration)
                iteration+=1
            except:
                try:
                    print('I am trying to push PURCHASE...')
                    if not isTest: driver.find_element_by_id(paymentIdBttn).click()
                    skipNextNext = skipNext = True
                    exceptNow = False
                except:
                    exceptNow = True
exceptNow = True
if not skipNext or not skipNextNext:
    while exceptNow:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name(secondAddressClassNameBttn).click()
            exceptNow = False
        except:
            exceptNow = True

print('Payment started...')
if not isTest and skipNextNext: driver.find_element_by_id(paymentIdBttn).click()
print('Payment ended...')```
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.